# Encryption ConnectionStrings App.config

Tags: c#, encryption, app-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

I have try to encrypt with code below, but it can use only on my PC, other PC can't connect to SQL server in my PC. anyone help me? thanks so much!!!
(I also try with aspnet_regiis.exe but have same problem)

```
        public static void ProtectSection(String sSectionName)
    {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("TFLManager.exe");

        // Get the section in the file.
        ConnectionStringsSection section = config.GetSection(sSectionName) as ConnectionStringsSection;
        // If the section exists and the section is not readonly, then protect the section.
        if (section != null)
        {
            if (!section.IsReadOnly())
            {
                // Protect the section.
                section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
                section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                // Save the change.
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you are looking for? You want to encrypt the Web.config file.

Comment: I want to encrypt app.config, after I use aspnet_regiis.exe encrypt, only my PC can connect to SQL server (on my PC), other PC can't connect.

Answer (score 0):

launch your Command prompt as an Administrator on the computer you want. 
At the Command Prompt, enter:

```
 cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

In case your web Config is located in "D:\Code\EncryptWebConfig" directory path, then enter the following to encrypt the ConnectionString:

```
ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStrings" "D:\Code\EncryptWebConfig"
```